# How to use pouchdb authentication without localhost?

Tags: authentication, pouchdb

I am working on windows offline application. And I had a look most of the example and demo in pouchdb, when we say serverless pouchdb then why do we need localhost to use pouchdb-authenticaltion.

If i use without localhost, i am getting this error message.

> This plugin only works for the http/https adapter. So you should use
>   new PouchDB("http://my.com:5984/mydb") instead."

Is there any possibilities to use basic user authentication in pouchdb without server url?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the authentication plugin for basic authentication or serverless local databases. For basic authentication to a remote CouchDb without https (obviously not very secure) you can do this:

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://yourusername:yourpassword@mycom:5984/dbname');
```

or this for just a local database (no CouchDb server):

```
var db = new PouchDB('dbname');
```

Comment: Thanks @IanC,Correct as you said without authentication plugin i can do very basic but no security, i was wondering there should be some option to do without url. If that is the limitation then need to move forward with some arrangements.

Comment: Manny - are your databases all offline/no server?

Comment: It is offline, windows application, electron with pouchdb

Comment: Keeping it completely secure is tricky then as there is no easy way (I know of) to protect the file on the local file system, aside from encrypted file systems/workstation passwords and so on.